# AngularJS - Filtering Greatest Value From JSON

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have JSON file with a list of numerical values:

```
{
    "Entries": {
        "Records" : [
            {
                "Name": "Mr Happy",
                "Gender": "Male",
                "Balance": "100"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Mr Sad",
                "Gender": "Male",
                "Balance": "50"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Mrs Grump",
                "Gender": "Female",
                "Balance": "2000"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Mr Loud",
                "Gender": "Male",
                "Balance": "1000"
            } 
        ]   

    }
}
```

I can display the list of values via a simple `ng-repeat` :

```
<li ng-repeat="account in Entries.Records">

    {{ account.Name }},  {{ account.Balance }} 

</li>
```

But how can i modify/filter this `ng-repeat` to only show the record with the highest balance?

---

Updated of full controller and service:

```
app.controller("MyController", function($scope, $http, getReportService) {

    $scope.EntriesRecords = [];

    getReportService.getReportData(function(data) {

        $scope.EntriesRecords = data.Entries.Records;

        $scope.maxBalanceAccount = findMaxBalanceAccount();
    });


    function findMaxBalanceAccount() {
        var result = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.EntriesRecords.length; i++) {
        var account = $scope.EntriesRecords[i];
            if (result == null || account.Balance > result.Balance) {
                result = account;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    console.log($scope.maxBalanceAccount);

});


app.factory('getReportService', function($http) {
    return {
        getReportData: function(done) {
            $http.get('/data/records.json')
            .success(function(data) { 
                done(data);
            })
            .error(function(error) {
                alert('An error occured');
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: plz have a deep look, this can help you http://www.kidsil.net/2013/09/filtering-with-angularjs/

Comment: @Jatt.net-Born2Code - i shouldnt have been down voted for this, it is different from the question you suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a ng-repeat. Find the account having the maximum balance using a function of your controller, and store it in the scope:

```
function findMaxBalanceAccount() {
    var result = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.Entries.Records.length; i++) {
        var account = $scope.Entries.Records[i];
        if (result == null || account.Balance > result.Balance) {
            result = account;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

$scope.maxBalanceAccount = findMaxBalanceAccount();
```

Now you can use it in the template:

```
{{ maxBalanceAccount.Name }},  {{ maxBalanceAccount.Balance }}
```

Note that variables and fields usually start with a lower-case letter in JavaScript.

Comment: tried the above, seeing this error in my console: Error: $scope.Entries.Records is undefined

Comment: modified my data mapping and error disappeared, however, when trying console.log($scope.maxBalanceAccount); i am seeing null

Comment: findMaxBalanceAccount() must be called when the scope has been populated with the JSON (so, probably, in an AJAX success handler). You should be able to figure that out.

Comment: findMaxBalanceAccount() is called after my http.get to the JSON file is successfull.

Comment: Edit your question, and show your code. After the call to $http.get(), you don't know if the call is successful yet. You'll only know that when the success callback is called, asynchronously.

Comment: You're storing the data in $scope.EntriesRecords, but you're iterating over $scope.Entries.Records in the findMaxBalanceAccount function. You must iterate over $scope.EntriesRecords instead, obviously. Your console.log() call will always print null, since you're displaying it before the function is called.

Comment: sorry that was a typo when updating my post, corrected. I an confirm in my project i an iterating over $scope.EntriesRecords